# New relics interactions not getting logged for signed apk

Tags: android, newrelic

I am using new relic for my app, all the interactions and http requests are getting logged accurately for my debug build. But for some reason it isn't working on my release build (signed apk).

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing an explanation of what you have tried to resolve the issue, including posting your configurations.

Comment: Check gradle flavors.